# Static Custom Progress Bar

Tags: objective-c, progress-bar

Since I'm new to learning Objective C I might not be explaining this right... but here goes.

I want a custom progress bar to remain in a constant location throughout 4 different view controllers but it begins to animate(by filling in) each time the user pressed the next button.
I attached photos of the designs I made for it.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: What language? You need to provide all the relevant information.

Comment: Sorry! Edited to Objective C